# MPI min function in reduce

Tags: mpi, min, reduce

I am trying to find the minimum number in my array of integers, however, it returns 0.

```
import mpi.*;
import java.util.Random;

class AddIntSR
{
public static void main(String[] params) throws Exception
{
    MPI.Init(params);
    int me = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
    int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();
    final int CHUNKSIZE = 1;
    final int ROOT = 0;
    Random rg = new Random();

    int [] bigBuf = new int[CHUNKSIZE *size];
    int [] smallBuf = new int[CHUNKSIZE];
    int [] minBuf = new int[1];

    int localTotal = 0;

    if (me == ROOT)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< bigBuf.length; i++)
            bigBuf[i] = rg.nextInt(10);

        for(int i = 0; i< bigBuf.length; i++)
            System.out.println("bigBuf "+bigBuf[i]);    
    }

    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Scatter(bigBuf,0,CHUNKSIZE,MPI.INT,smallBuf,0,CHUNKSIZE,MPI.INT,ROOT);

    if(me!= ROOT)
    {
        System.out.println("smallBuf "+me+ ": "+smallBuf[0]);
        for(int i = 0; i < smallBuf.length; i++)
            localTotal += smallBuf[i];
    }

    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Reduce(new int[]{localTotal},0,bigBuf,0,1,MPI.INT,MPI.MAX,ROOT);
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Reduce(new int[]{localTotal},0,minBuf,0,1,MPI.INT,MPI.MIN,ROOT);

    if(me == ROOT)
    {   
        System.out.println(bigBuf[0]);
        System.out.println(minBuf[0]);
    }
}
}
```

I am not sure why it does not work. The maximum function seems to work fine.
Also, how would I be able to access the integer that is sent to processor 0 so it is included in the min/max comparison?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MIN` reduction always results in `0` since `localTotal` is always `0` in rank `ROOT` and this is indeed the minimum value.

After the `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Scatter` call, all process including `ROOT` will have a piece of data in their `smallBuf`. Therefore you should remove the following conditional, i.e.:

```java
if(me!= ROOT)
{
    System.out.println("smallBuf "+me+ ": "+smallBuf[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < smallBuf.length; i++)
        localTotal += smallBuf[i];
}
```

should become simply:

```java
System.out.println("smallBuf "+me+ ": "+smallBuf[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < smallBuf.length; i++)
    localTotal += smallBuf[i];
```